# Nested ternary operator not returning as expected

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm trying to wrap my head around nested ternary ops.

The value of colorVariant is either 'success', 'info', 'error', or 'default'.

```
props.colorVariant == 'success' ? 'green' : 'info' ? 'gray' : 'error' ? 'red' : 'default' ? 'black' : 'purple'
```

At the moment, I've set the value to 'default' as I'd like to see it make it all the way to the end, but as it stands, the colour being returned is gray.

Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: You should use a map (object) with the keys/values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to carry out the comparison in each condition, eg:

```
props.colorVariant == 'success'
  ? 'green'
  : props.colorVariant === 'info'
    ? 'gray'
    : props.colorVariant === 'error'
       ? // ...
```

But it'd make much more sense to use an object here:

```
const colorsByVariant = {
  success: 'green',
  info: 'gray',
  error: 'red',
  default: 'black',
};
const color = colorsByVariant[props.colorVariant] ?? 'purple';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
props = {colorVariant: ''} // just here for the demo

const color = props.colorVariant == 'success' ? 'green' :
props.colorVariant == 'info' ? 'gray' :
props.colorVariant == 'error' ? 'red' :
props.colorVariant == 'default' ? 'black' : 'purple';

console.log('color:', color); // purple
```

```
props.colorVariant == 'success' ? 'green' : props.colorVariant == 'info' ? 'gray' : props.colorVariant == 'error' ? 'red' : props.colorVariant == 'default' ? 'black' : 'purple'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the variable. If not the first not empty string is truthy.

```
props.colorVariant === 'success'
    ? 'green'
    : props.colorVariant === 'info'
        ? 'gray'
        : props.colorVariant === 'error'
            ? 'red'
            : props.colorVariant === 'default'
                ? 'black'
                : 'purple'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the condition after the `:`
instead of

```
    props.colorVariant == 'success' ? 'green' : 'info' ? 'gray' : 'error' ? 'red' : 'default' ? 'black' : 'purple'
```

you should do the following

```
props.colorVariant == 'success' ? 'green' : props.colorVariant == 'info' ? 'gray' : props.colorVariant == 'error' ? 'red' : props.colorVariant == 'default' ? 'black' : 'purple'
```

At the moment You get 'gray' because:

`props.colorVariant` is different to `success` then it goes to `info` but there is no condition so it's true (because a string is casted to a booleaqn is always true) then you got `gray`